send message from BroadcastReceiver to Module or JS side in react-native
I am using this project as a reference for creating geofence in react-native with a custom native module in Android. As part of this I am able to detect entry and exit events in BroadcastReceiver, which is in a separate file, as in the above repo.
Now, I want to send the information from BroadcastReceiver to either my module or the JS side. The approach taken in the above link is not working as reactContext is null, since it's a static member.
I tried using LiveData, LocalManager etc. but they didn't work. What's the best mathodology to use here? All I want is to post a message from BroadcastReceiver to the JS side. I am trying to get from the message handle to the module file as reactContext would be available and can send with it using DeviceEventEmitter. I am not able to achieve this.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
